# Deploy to a machine in the network using git

Tags: git, deployment

I am developing an app and version-control it using git at github. Now there is another machine for testing purposes without access to the internet, so I cannot pull the changes from github. I am able to connect to the test server through the network.

My question is: is it possible to push changes from the development repository to the test repository directly and if so - how (can I setup the test-machine as remote)?

I am new to version-control and to git, so please be nice  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple share to the test repo should be enough

```
git remote add test file:////path/to/test/repo
```

or simply:

```
git remote add test /path/to/test/repo
```

(See [git remote](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html))

That is enough to make a push to the test repo.
See [this example](http://justaddwater.dk/2009/02/21/using-local-file-based-git-server-laziness/)